# JS. Как удалить теги из строки? <span> 111,22 . 0 </span>? И оставить содержимое?

Tags: javascript

Точку и теги спан, и ноль отдельные нужно удалить.
Должна получится строка "111,22"

Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Вы явно делаете что-то не то. Вместо того, чтобы парсить HTML, попробуйте [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

Comment: Все уже сам решил вопрос, хоть плохо да и ладно.
`
 tx_in = tx_in.replace(new RegExp("<span>",'g'),"");
 tx_in = tx_in.replace(new RegExp("</span>",'g'),"");
 tx_in = tx_in.replace(",",".");
 tx_in = tx_in.replace(" 0 ","");
`

Comment: ответ на вопрос лучше добавить как ответ на вопрос, а не ввиде комментария. Чтобы удалить html теги, нет нужды регулярные выражения использовать: [javascript имеет доступ к html парсеру (можно воспользоваться textContent, предложенный @VladD](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5002111/4279).